# IOS5 - Custom UITableViewCell doesn't show content

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm encountering an issue with my application, most specifically with a `UITableView` and its `UITableViewCells`. Here's the problem : I created a `UITableView` within a `UIView`, with custom `UITableViewCell`. I've two controllers involved :

- ListController.m
- ListCellController.m

In IB, I linked the items of the cell to the IBOutlets I manually created in the header file of the cell controller.

Here's the code for the ListCellController.h/m :

```
// .h
@class Item;

@interface ListCellController : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) Item *item;   
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *itemName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *dates;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *itemId;     
@end

// .m

// @synthetize stuff

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    return self;
}

- (void)setItem:(Item *)item
{
    _item = item;

    self.itemName.text = _list.itemName;
    self.itemId.text = _list.itemId;
    self.dates.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Du %@ au %@", _list.date, _list.date];
}
```

And here's the code for the ListController.h/m :

```
// .h
@interface ListController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    UITableView *cellList;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *cellList;
@end

// .m
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_list count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"List cell";
    ListCellController *cell = [cellList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ListCellController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.itemId.text = cell.item.itemId;
    cell.itemName.text = cell.item.itemName;
    cell.dates.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From %@ to %@", cell.item.date, cell.item.date];
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cellList deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The problem I have is that when I launch the application, I see nothing on my cell. No content, no error, no nothing, blank cell.

Just to mention, I'm also using storyboarding here.

Has anyone already encountered this issue ? How could I solve it please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you link the delegate & dataSource in IB? I don't see you setting the delegate in code.

Comment: I only set the dataSource in IB. It seems I didn't do anything about the delegate. But I'm quite new to IOS development, and I don't really know what to link in this case...

Comment: whichever header class contains your tableView Outlet also needs the delegate set, the same way as the datasource.

Comment: It may also be related to your array that you are using as a data source. When/where is `_list` getting filled out?

Comment: I make a call in the viewDidLoad function that fills the _list. It makes no change when I set the delegate as well as the datasource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have custom cell on UITableView, you have to do something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"List cell";
    ListCellController *cell = (ListCellController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

   if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListCellController" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (ListCellController *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cell.item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.itemId.text = cell.item.segmentCode;
    cell.itemName.text = cell.item.hotelName;
    cell.dates.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Du %@ au %@", cell.item.checkin, cell.item.checkout];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @tsabz - are _you_ working with storyboards? You must mention that in the question, because if you are, dequeue will always return a cell, and all your cells will be initialized using initWithCoder.

Comment: Yes I'm using storyboarding, i'll specify it in the initial post.

Comment: I've got my problem solved with this anwser. I just created a new .xib file and pasted the code above. Everything is working like a charm now. Thanks !